# Проблема с .json в wpf c#

Tags: c#, json, wpf

При нажатии на кнопку в методе `Button_Click` у меня должна производится запись в JSON-файл, но вместо этого у меня вылезает такая ошибка:

```
System.ArgumentException: ".NET number values such as positive and negative infinity cannot be written as valid JSON."
```

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace лаба_5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
        claik1 claik11 = new claik1();
        public List<string> Login { get; set; }
        public List<string> Password { get; set; }
       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MainWindow(List<string> login, List<string> password)
        {
            Login = login;
            Password = password;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
       
            if (passwordbox1.Password == passwordbox2.Password & !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxname1.Text) & !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxemail.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordbox1.Password) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordbox2.Password) )
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("user.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    List<String> Name = new List<string>() { "Ярослав", "Илья", "Рома" };
                    List<String> Age = new List<string>() { "18", "10", "16" };

                    MainWindow tom = new MainWindow(Name, Age);
                    await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<MainWindow>(fs, tom);
                }

                passwordbox1.Clear();
                textboxname1.Clear();
                passwordbox2.Clear();
                textboxemail.Clear();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Введите данные корректно");
                passwordbox1.Clear();
                passwordbox2.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void butonlogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textboxemail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            passwordbox2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            butonregistering.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            buntavtoris.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            textboxname1.Clear();
            passwordbox1.Clear();
        }

        private void buttonreg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textboxemail.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            passwordbox2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            butonregistering.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            buntavtoris.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            textboxname1.Clear();
            passwordbox1.Clear();
            
        }

        private void buntavtoris_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream fike = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Ярослав\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\info.txt",FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fike);

            string h = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] l = h.Split('\n');
            streamReader.Close();
            
            for(int i = 0; i < l.Length; i++)
            {
                string g = textboxname1.Text + ";" + passwordbox1.Password + ";";
                string hf = l[i].Trim();
              
                if (g == hf)
                {
                    claik11.Show();
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл сериализации всего окна со всеми его потрохами? Экономите на одном классе, куда можно все ваши данные положить, и имеете подобные проблемы. Опишите класс для сериализации, заполните его данными перед сериализацией, его и сериализуйте.

Comment: вы пытаетесь сериализировать ВСЁ ОКНО!! вместо кусочка данных. У вашего окна где-то в "глубине души" есть свойство, значение которого - бесконечность. А в JSON бесконечность записать нельзя